# Validate input fields after changing input values with jQuery or echoing values with PHP

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin.  I have a simple function that copies one input's value to another input.

```
function sameAsShipping() {
    $('#billingFirstName').val($('#firstName').val());
}
```

I would like to validate the newly copied input values using the valid() method.  I'm trying to call the valid() method if the input's value isn't blank.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input, select").each(function() {
        if(!$(this).val() === "")
            $(this).valid();
    });
});
```

Along with manipulating input values with jQuery, if the form is submitted and there is an error, I echo the previously submitted values.  I would also like these to validate these fields on load, however, only if there is a value in the input.

```
<input type="text" id="billingFirstName" name="billingFirstName" class="required" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['firstName'])){echo $_SESSION['firstName'];} ?>">
```

Comment: PHP generates the page on the server, long before any JavaScript.  I'm just trying to figure out how PHP has to do with anything here.  Please show more code or explain this a little better.  Thanks.

Comment: Where/how are you calling `.valid()`?  I can see it inside your `.each()` method but when/how is that called?  Within DOM ready?, another event?

Comment: Yes, within DOM ready.

Comment: @Sparky Php doesn't have anything to do with it, although I just wanted to make sure the fix would apply for both scenarios.

Comment: Still not sure what you want this code to do.  If you want to validate all fields on load, then just use `.valid()` inside DOM ready by itself.  Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/XcaD2/

Comment: So much is still missing.  What is calling `sameAsShipping()`?  Please explain better what you're really wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created DOM objects cannot be selected with javascript directly. You need to select a static element that existed before any DOM manipulation.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body :input, select").each(function() {
        if(!$(this).val() === "")
            $(this).valid();
    });
});
```

body element is static (not created) by javascript and so can be selected. From tehre you can navigate to any element as normal. You also do not need to use body. Any element that is static html or created by back-end programming language will work.

Alternatively you could use [liveQuery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) plugin for jQuery.